Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" option missing during installation from bootable USB
I’m trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop, which currently has Windows installed, using a bootable USB drive, however during the installation process I ran into an issue. On the screen where it asks, "How do you want to install Ubuntu?", the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" does not appear. Instead, I only see the following options:
   Erase disk and install Ubuntu
   Manual installation
This worried me because I don’t want to lose my data or overwrite my Windows installation. I decided to stop the process to avoid any issues.
Here’s my current setup:
Laptop: - ASUS VivoBook

Windows is installed and working properly.

I booted the Ubuntu installer from a bootable USB drive.

I haven’t made any changes to the partitions on my disk.


What could be causing this issue? How can I proceed with installing Ubuntu without losing Windows and ensure that both operating systems are accessible at boot?

From Windows, you need to shrink the partition and make unpartitioned space to install Ubuntu.

Check if Bitlocker is enabled in Windows. Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?
